# OperationalError during adding records with polish signs through django-admin

Tags: python, mysql, django

I use Django with Mysql database.

During adding records to database through `django-admin` with specjal characters like `ąęćźż` I get:

```
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC4\\x86wicz...' for column 'object_repr' at row 1")
```

It happens only during adding records through admin panel. I don't have any problems adding records with special character through other views or raw query through `mysql console`.

Is there any simple solution?

I tried to execute every of this query:

```
ALTER TABLE event_coursetype CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER DATABASE Events CHARACTER SET utf8;
SET NAMES utf8;
SET NAMES latin2;
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have as your default charset in settings.py?

This is what I have in my settings.py:

```
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'UTF-8'
```

Anyways mysql and charsets can be a bit of a pain in the behind sometimes.
See this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/6mksng/how_we_almost_lost_an_important_client_because_of/

Which links to this article:
https://www.eversql.com/mysql-utf8-vs-utf8mb4-whats-the-difference-between-utf8-and-utf8mb4/